# I want to know the exact method used by rand() to generate random numbers in gcc compiler of linux.

Tags: gcc, random

I want to know the exact method used to generate random numbers in gcc compiler of linux.

I know that the Linear Congruental Generator is used to generate random numbers in gcc which has general formula:

X(n+1) = (a* X(n) +c) mod m

and I came to know that the general formula used, has these constant values as given in wikipedia :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

which are m=2^3, a =1103515245 and 12345

But the results obtained by putting these constants do not match with the result obtained by rand() function in gcc.

Can someone please help me where i am wrong, or is there something which i dont know.

Comment: Are you using a constant seed?

Comment: It is unclear which rand() function you're talking about. gcc does not have one. It is a compiler. rand() is a library function. There's an implementation in stdlib and one in cstdlib. I assume you're speaking of one of those. The libraries generally used with gcc are open source, as far as I know, so it  ought to be a simple matter to go look at the source and see exactly how they're implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Do the numbers match this:
http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/random/

Otherwise, the source code is here:
http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/rand.c;h=92916e833f7fc94ac16a2bd047c33f8a6ef6ec49;hb=HEAD
which leads to here:
http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random.c;h=ff6bdd2b5d5a8f7633a914282f4c6ab1991df0cf;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 0):

There looks like a call to DES::SetKey(unsigned long long int); in the stdlib.h don't know if this is anything to do with the Random Generator function but you never know as there is a much faster version of the DES encryption/decryption algorithm which was the one used  once used in the old version of GNUPG which actually used DES as the encryption/decryption system of choice so this is what they might be using to generate random numbers.